# Filtering across related models with SQLAlchemy core API (using AIOPG)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, aiopg

I'm trying to do something I'm fairly sure is simple using AIOPG, which can use sqlalchemy's core API. My SQL is not great, so that's where I'm falling down here.

**models**

```py
class School(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'schools'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)


sa_school = School.__table__


class SubjectCategory(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'subject_categories'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String(63))


sa_subject_category = SubjectCategory.__table__


class Subject(Base):
    __tablename__ == 'subjects'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String(63))
    category = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('subject_categories.id'), nullable=False)


sa_subject = Subject.__table__


class SchoolSubject(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'school_subjects'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    school = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('schools.id'), nullable=False)
    subject = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('subjects.id'), nullable=False)


sa_school_subject = SchoolSubject.__table__
```

So I'm just trying to get all `schools` which teach subjects that have a certain `subject_category` ID.

Currently I have:

```
from sqlalchemy import select, join

school_c = sa_school.c
school_subj_c = sa_school_subject.c


async def get_schools(subject=None, subj_cat=None)
    query = select(
        [school_c.id, school_c.name]
    ).select_from(sa_school.join(sa_school_subject)
    if subj_cat:
        # Then I need to filter where a school_subj.subject.category == subj_cat
        pass
    elif subject:
        query = query.where(sa_school_subject.c.subject == subj)

    cur = await conn.execute(query)
    return [dict(b) async for b in cur]
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of faffing, I can simply do:

```
query = select(
    [school_c.id, school_c.name]
).select_from(sa_school.join(sa_school_subject.join(sa_subject)))
```